# Camel not able to pick 0 byte file

Tags: file-io, apache-camel, sftp

I have camel configured to pick file from ftp. but where any empty file is placed it fail to pick it and log same event continuously:

```
2015-07-14 19:53:11,005 WARN  [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.strategy.FtpChangedExclusiveReadLockStrategy] (Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - ftp://abc.com/responsefiles) Cannot acquire read lock within 20000 millis. Will skip the file: RemoteFile[REFUND07102015.141730.csv]
```

my camel config is :

```
sftp://[servername]/responsefiles?username=[username]&password=[password]&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=5000&noop=false&preMove=.processing&move=.done
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You likely need to configure `readLockMinLength=0` to allow picking up empty files. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/file2

Comment: its SFTP not file. so will that flag flag applies to SFT?

Comment: Yes many of the options for file is also used by ftp as it extends file. See the info box on top of the ftp options, where it says that: http://camel.apache.org/ftp2